# Second level looping over dictionaries

Tags: python, class, for-loop

In building a class with an out line like below I would like the behaviour of  the for loops to, if done once: just give the keys as normal an then move on to the next line of code. But if a second loop is set up inside the first loop it would give the keys on the first loop and then ea value in the sequences in the second loop.  The problem I can't figure out is how to set up this under **iter**.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cont1 = [1,2,3,4]
        self.cont2 = ('a','b','c')

def __iter__(self):
    pass # ???????
```

Something like this:

```
dct = dict(container1=[5,6,7,8], container2=('a','b','c')

if one loop is used:

   for ea in dct:
        print(ea)
print("Howdy")

'containter1'
'containter2'
Howdy
```

If a nest loop is used:

```
for ea in dct:
    print(ea)
    for i in dct.get(ea):
        print(i)

'container1'
5
6
...
'container2'
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, you could just copy how dictionaries implement `dict.get` and `dict.__iter__`:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cont1 = [1,2,3,4]
        self.cont2 = ('a','b','c')

    def __iter__(self):
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not attr.startswith('_') and attr != 'get':
                yield attr

    def get(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)
```

It's not a very good approach, however. Looking at the attributes of your object at runtime isn't a good idea, because it will break when you subclass and it will add needless complexity. Instead, just use a dictionary internally:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = {
            'cont1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
            'cont2': ('a', 'b', 'c')
        }

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.container)

    def get(self, key):
        return self.container.get(key)
```

Comment: That helps!  The second one especially.  Playing around with it now  it seems a little clunky with the get and all, but it works! and it gives a chance to move forward.

Comment: [@FamousJameous's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39754173/464744) I think is the easiest to use, since `dict.iteritems()` is what you'd use in the first place if doing this to a regular dict.

Comment: It seems intuitive to me that a nested for loop on a dictionary would provide an iteration over the value portion of the key : value pair.(if iterable).  I realize there may be objects that are not, but it would often times be useful.  Looking at it from another perspective I can't think of anything else a nest loop would provide, so why doesn't it?

Comment: @user3163030: What do you mean by "nested for loop" in the case of a dictionary? `for key in d`, `for key, value in d.items()`, and `for value in d.values()` allow you to iterate over any part of a dictionary with a single `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

How would you feel about this:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cont1 = [1,2,3,4]
        self.cont2 = ('a','b','c')
        self.conts = {'container1':self.cont1, 'container2':self.cont2}

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.conts.iteritems()

dct = MyClass()
print('One loop')
for mi in dct:
    print(mi)
print('='*40)
print('Nested loops')
for name, values in dct:
    print(name)
    for i in values:
        print(i)
```

Which outputs:

```
One loop
container1
container2
========================================
Nested loops
container1
1
2
3
4
container2
a
b
c
```

### Update

---

I don't know that I would really recommend this, but this seems to more closely fit what the OP wants:

```
class MyIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, name, values):
        self.vals = iter(values)
        self.name = name

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.vals

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cont1 = [1,2,3,4]
        self.cont2 = ('a','b','c')
        self.conts = [MyIterator('container1', self.cont1),
                      MyIterator('container2', self.cont2)]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.conts)

dct = MyClass()
for mi in dct:
    print(mi)
    for i in mi:
        print(i)
```

This is the only way I can think of to be able to print the name and then iterate over it as the values list. This works by overriding the `__str__`  method to change how the object gets "stringified". But as I said earlier, I think you would be better served with the first part of the answer.

Sorry, just realized [nauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39754576/3901060) already showed something like this.

Comment: I looked at that and what I really was looking to have done is 1 loop(stand alone) - gives keys.  2nd loop optional - gives ea item in the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a second class like this

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data  = [MyClass2({'cont1' : [1,2,3,4]}),MyClass2({'cont2' : ('a','b','c')})]    

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.data:
            yield item



class MyClass2():
    def __init__(self, mydict):
        self.d = mydict

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.d.values():
            for value in item:
                yield value

    def __repr__(self):
        return(list(self.d.keys())[0])


    m = MyClass()

for k in m:
    print(k)
    for val in k:
        print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that simply by implementing `__iter__`. `__iter__` should return an *iterator*, that is, an object that keeps the state of an iteration (the current position in a sequence of items) and has a method `next` that returns with each invocation the next item in the sequence.

If your object has nested sequences you can implement an iterator that will traverse only the external sequence, or one that will traverse both
the external and the internal sequences - in a depth-first or a breath-first fashion - but it does not make sense to use nested loops on the same iterable:

```
# iterate over every item in myobj
for x in myobj:
    ...
    # iterate over every item again? not likely what you want!
    for y in myobj:
```

A more likely situation is:

```
for x in myob:
    ...
    for y in x:
        ...
```